# In Excel, how do I add a value per row?

Tags: excel, vba

Consider a specific cell with the entry 30000. What I want to do is: increment the value by just 1 for every row that is following this cell. 
There must be an easy way to do this, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Type in your starting value in the first row
2. On the second row type "=" + click on the cell with your starting value + type "+1" and enter.
3. Hover your mouse over the bottom right corner of the second cell with your equation until you see a black plus sign.
4. Drag it down as many rows as you want.

Here's a picture:
[image: Here's a picture]

Comment: jep, that's what I meant! Thx a lot, man! - However, one more question: When I do what you suggested, everything works out. But if I later decide to delete a row, Excel is not able to calculate the entries of the rows following the deleted row. I would have to perform your mentioned steps 3-4 again. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @user503842 after you delete a row, you can go to the first cell after that, now with a #REF! and just key in the formula again. Since you already told Excel that you wanted the following cells afterwards to have the same formula, just changing one cell is enough.

eg. using my example above
If I deleted row 7, the values starting from row 7 will have #REF!. Just type in "=A6+1" into row 7 again and the rest of the cells should go back to normal

Comment: If you're looking at having the entries for the original row 8 stay as "8" and not "7" after you delete the row, the most straightforward way I can think of is to hide the row instead of deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

So `E242` already has 30000, `E243` already has 30001 and you want to permanently add one to each value?

- Type `1` in a blank cell and copy the cell (`Ctrl+C`).
- Select the range `E242:E276` and right-click.
- Select `Paste Special` to make a pop-out menu appear.
  At the bottom of the pop-out menu select `Paste Special` again.
- In the dialog box that opens select `Add` and click `OK`.

This will add your copied number to the value in the selected cells.